# QML Loading View during function runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I am attempting to create a qml button object that displays a screen for the duration of a function's runtime. I plan to use this loading screen when I need to parse through a larger dataset/run a slower function. Currently this is what I have come up with.

```
//LoadingButton.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item
{
    id: impl
    function callbackFunction() { console.log("This is a dummy funciton and needs to be overwritten in the implementation") } //empty dummy function

    property alias style: button.style
    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            loadingScreen.visible = true;
            console.log("Loading should be visible")
            impl.callbackFunction();
            loadingScreen.visible = false;
            console.log("Loading should be hidden")
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        width: 500
        height: 500
        x:0
        y:0
        z: 60
        id: loadingScreen
        color: "red"
        visible: false
    }
}
```

This example runs the callbackFunction once overwritten in the parent object correctly, but the visibility of the Rectangle does not change until the slower function is completed. Also the application freezes until it finishes.

Is there any way to force the Rectangle to show/hide mid-javascript function execution?

Comment: that won’t work: while the function is executed, the UI thread blocks and the UI won’t  be updated/be responsive. The operation would need to work asynchronously/in another thread and notify the UI thread when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution is of course to move your slow function to a background thread. That way the GUI stays responsive.

If you want to keep the callbackFunction in same thread as the GUI, you can use a Timer that will delay the start of the slow function until the loading screen is shown. Please note that the GUI will be blocked during the execution of the slow function.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item
{
    id: impl

    function callbackFunction() {
        console.log("This is a dummy funciton and needs to be overwritten in the implementation")
        var cnt = 0
        var largeNumber = 1
        while (cnt < 99999999) {
            largeNumber += largeNumber/3
            cnt++
        }

        //put this at the end of your slow function
        loadingScreen.visible = false;
        console.log("Loading should be hidden")
    }

    property alias style: button.style
    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            loadingScreen.visible = true;
            console.log("Loading should be visible")
            timer.start()
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 500
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: impl.callbackFunction()
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: loadingScreen
        width: 500
        height: 500
        x:0
        y:0
        z: 60
        color: "red"
        visible: false
        BusyIndicator {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            running: loadingScreen.visible
        }
    }
}
```